# Find prime numbers $p,q$ such that: $pq| p^p+q^q+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Le $p,q$ be prime numbers such that: $pq| p^p+q^q+1$

> Find $p,q$

I don't have any ideas about this problem :(

Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't figured out the problem yet, and I don't know if this helps any: $q^q \equiv -1 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 2):

If $pq | p^p + q^q + 1$ then also $p | p^p + q^q + 1$. We know that $p|p^p$ so $p$ also has to divide $q^q + 1$. The same we get for $q : q|p^p + 1$.
With congruence we can write:
$$q^q \equiv -1 \mod p$$
$$p^p \equiv -1 \mod q$$
From Fermat's Little Theorem we have two more congruences:
$$q^p \equiv q \mod p$$
$$p^q \equiv p \mod q$$
Now you only have to solve this set of congruences.
The only two solutions $(p,q)$ are $(2, 5)$ and $(5, 2)$.

Comment: This is not a correct solution. After having those 2 pairs of congruences, you didn't fully prove why the only solutions are $2$ and $5$. The correct approach should include using the ord for modular arithmetic $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is probably a method to solving this other than guessing and checking, but I guessed and checked anyway.

Let $p = 2$ and $q = 5$.  Then $pq = 2\cdot 5 = 10$.

$$p^{p} + q^{q} + 1 = 2^{2} + 5^{5} + 1 = 4 + 3125 + 1 = 3130$$

and $3130 \div 10 = 313$, so we do have $$2 \cdot 5 \mid (2^{2} + 5^{5} + 1)$$

Comment: This does not solve the problem of "Finding all". I am sure the author wanted to prove why $2, 5$ is the only solution to the above congruence relation.